# How to save a leaflet map (created with rMaps) as a html widget?

Tags: r, leaflet, htmlwidgets, rmaps

**Question 1**
I try to save a leaflet map created with rMaps [here](http://rmaps.github.io/blog/posts/leaflet-heat-maps/index.html), into a html file.

```
L2 <- Leaflet$new()
L2$setView(c(29.7632836,  -95.3632715), 10)
L2$tileLayer(provider = "MapQuestOpen.OSM")
L2
library(htmlwidgets)

saveWidget(L2,"t.html")
```

But I got an error:

```
Error in envRefInferField(x, what, getClass(class(x)), selfEnv) : 
  ‘width’ is not a valid field or method name for reference class “Leaflet”
```

**Answer 1**
Thanks to LukeA, we can use this syntaxe:

```
leaflet(width = "100%") %>% 
  addProviderTiles("MapQuestOpen.OSM") %>% 
  setView(-95.3632715, 29.7632836, zoom = 10) -> L2
```

**Question 2**
But then, how to add addAssets and setTemplate:

```
# Add leaflet-heat plugin. Thanks to Vladimir Agafonkin
L2$addAssets(jshead = c(
  "http://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.heat/dist/leaflet-heat.js"
))

# Add javascript to modify underlying chart
L2$setTemplate(afterScript = sprintf("
<script>
  var addressPoints = %s
  var heat = L.heatLayer(addressPoints).addTo(map)           
</script>
", rjson::toJSON(crime_dat)
))

L2
```

**Answer 2**
Again, thanks to LukeA, we have the answer:

```
L2$save(tf <- tempfile(fileext = ".html"),standalone=TRUE)
```

**Question 3**

In fact, my initial problem is that I can't write the code in rmarkdown, in order to generate directly the map in the html document.

Now I can save the map alone. But how to integrate it into the html document ? The rapide solution is to make an iframe. It there any other more elegant solutions ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although not a direct answer to your question, I suggest an alternative approach that yields a similar result:

```
library(leaflet)
library(htmlwidgets)
leaflet() %>% 
  addProviderTiles("MapQuestOpen.OSM") %>% 
  setView(-95.3632715, 29.7632836, zoom = 10) -> m 
saveWidget(m, tf <- tempfile(fileext = ".html"))
```

or, using `rMaps`:

```
library(plyr)
library(rCharts)
library(rMaps)
data(crime, package = 'ggmap')
crime_dat = ddply(crime, .(lat, lon), summarise, count = length(address))
crime_dat = toJSONArray(na.omit(unname(crime_dat)), json = F)

L2 <- Leaflet$new()
L2$setView(c(29.7632836,  -95.3632715), 10)
L2$tileLayer(provider = "MapQuestOpen.OSM")
# Add leaflet-heat plugin. Thanks to Vladimir Agafonkin
L2$addAssets(jshead = c(
  "http://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.heat/dist/leaflet-heat.js"
))
# Add javascript to modify underlying chart
L2$setTemplate(afterScript = sprintf("
<script>
  var addressPoints = %s
  var heat = L.heatLayer(addressPoints).addTo(map)           
</script>
", rjson::toJSON(crime_dat)
))

L2$save(tf <- tempfile(fileext = ".html"),standalone=TRUE)
```

Comment: Excellent ! Thank you. In fact, I wanted to write leafet in this way, and add leaflet(width = "100%"). Then it didn't work when I tried Leaflet$new(width="100%"). So I was wondering if the parameter width is since then left in the function. If so, how to "reinitiate" the leaflet map ? And the rmaps example, extra features are added. How to do it with pipelines ?
L2$addAssets(jshead = c(
  "http://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.heat/dist/leaflet-heat.js"
))
and 
L2$setTemplate()

Comment: You can set the width in `leaflet()` - e.g. `leaflet(width="50%")`. Concerning some "extra features" (?) - please browse through https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/

Comment: By "extra features", I mean those in the example of rmaps: addAssets, and setTemplate. They are not in leaflet homepage.

Comment: I dunno how you could embed Leaflet.heat within the leaflet package. Maybe post a new question or directly ask the package author? Or use custom & static pre-calculated contours?

Comment: I just looked into the github issues of `leaflet`: [this issue](https://github.com/rstudio/leaflet/pull/174) seems to address your needs.

Comment: Thank you very much @lukeA. In fact, the code with `Leaflet$new()` is from the package rmaps. And It seems that the addHeatmap function is not yet officially in the leaflet package. I got `could not find function "addHeatmap"`.

Comment: No, it's not part of `leatlet`, yet (?). Install it using `devtools::install_github("rstudio/leaflet#174")` if you want (didn't work for me). You could also look at how [@timelyportfolio](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1552388/timelyportfolio) implemented it.

Comment: Thank you very much Luke. I also edited my question ;)